# asp.net mvc routing when passed parameter contains dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have very basic routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
```

The problem is that it works perfectly in all simple cases, like `www.xxx.yy/pages/filter/test`". As soon as I add dot "." to {id} part it fails, 
returning 'The resource cannot be found.' It happens for `www.xxx.yy/pages/filter/test.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The resource cannot be found." error when there is a "dot" at the end of the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-ur)

Answer (score 5):

Just add a slash "/" at the end of the URL: `www.xxx.yy/pages/filter/test./`

See: [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis).

Comment: This was really great. Thanks buddy :D

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post: ["The resource cannot be found." error when there is a "dot" at the end of the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-url)