# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Point (.) in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am using the following route to map to a controller that finds something by a Tag

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchByTagname",
            url: "Search/Tag/{tagname}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", Action="Tag", tagname = "" });
```

It works fine, if there is no point (.) in URL.

Calling /Search/Tag/ASP.NET gives me 404.

Thank you & regards

Stephan

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis
It'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, i searched for "point" but not for "dots", sorry for that.