# Allow runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests for one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I need to turn on runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests for a particular MVC controller that expects a filename as its parameter `(i.e. http://server/api/file/00_08112010MC41670.txt)`, but I don't want to incur this penalty for everything on the site by putting it in the root of web.config (see comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607685/264607).  Is there a way to turn this on only for a particular controller in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to do this:

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html