# ASPX Page Name Contains Dot (.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I create an ASPX page that has the character '.' in its name?
If I name the page: "MyName.com", it will give me a lot of errors afterward.
I'm using .NET 4

MSDN could do it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx). Check the URL.

Here are some of the errors I'm getting:

Error   4   Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Sample Telerik\AnotherDotSolution\AnotherDotSolution\MyTest.com.aspx.cs  11  2   AnotherDotSolution

Error   2   { expected  C:\Sample Telerik\AnotherDotSolution\AnotherDotSolution\MyTest.com.aspx.cs  10  29  AnotherDotSolution

and also in the designer:

Error   8   The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Sample Telerik\AnotherDotSolution\AnotherDotSolution\MyTest.com.aspx.designer.cs 13  33  AnotherDotSolution

Comment: Could this SO be of use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Comment: It's not the `.`. I suspect it's the `.com` that's causing confusion

Comment: @NicholasV. I don't think that that is relevant since it's MVC

Comment: You are going to need to provide some more information. I just added `mypage.this.aspx` to my project, built it and browsed under debug to the page without issue using .NET 4.5.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4 if that makes any difference. I added that to the question.

Comment: You mention getting "a lot of errors afterward"...care to provide maybe one of these?

Comment: To follow your example literally, `MyName.com` isn't a valid file extension for your view. It needs to be `MyName.com.aspx`, which matches the same format as the MSDN article you linked. Additionally this is standard behavior of the file system. You could have a jpeg named `MyImage.png.gif.jpg`. The last dot starts the beginning of the file extension.

Comment: You also need to edit your question and tell us or show what errors you're getting. There's a lot of context missing from this. Until then I'm voting to close.

Comment: Am I the only person who's getting this problem?! I will modify the question right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

The `CodeBehind` of the aspx file `@Page` directive determines the name of the class file that needs to contain the class referenced in `Inherits`. So you could get away with having a dot in the page name as long as you are willing to hand code the class name in the aspx and aspx.cs files.

### Webform1.Stuff.aspx

Note the `@Page` directive or whatever it's called. The `CodeBehind` and `Inherit` bits.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.Stuff.cs" Inherits="WebFormsApp1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Webform1.Stuff.cs

```
namespace WebFormsApp1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I was able to compile and run this page.

Comment: @yazanpro - just because the same company wrote IE... hey wait a minute!!

Comment: This leaves out URL Rewriting, which is a big part of the picture.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what do you mean by URL Rewriting in this case?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your code-behind likely has an invalid class declaration. It probably looks like this:

```
public partial class MyTest.com : System.Web.UI.Page
```

And should look like this:

```
public partial class MyTest__com : System.Web.UI.Page
```

You will also need to make sure your `.aspx` uses the proper `Inherits`:

```
Inherits="yournamespace.MyTest__com"
```