# MVC Routing Bug or i am missing something

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't access:

```
http://localhost:54158/Bull/Details/S.No%20GERRY
http://localhost:54158/Bull/Edit/S.No%20Gurukul
http://localhost:54158/Bull/Edit/S.No%20GR%2013
```

While I can access:

```
http://localhost:54158/Bull/Details/GR%20001
http://localhost:54158/Bull/Edit/TP%20001
```

In short, I can't access an URL with .(periods) as parameter.

```
public ActionResult Details(String id)
{
    Bull bull = db.Bulls.Find(id);
    if (bull == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(bull);
}
```

I tried placing breakpoints in my code, but for the inaccessible URLs, the actions that should be triggered, aren't.

Comment: Can you show us your defined routes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Answer (score 0):

[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2013/01/16/handing-mvc-paths-with-dots-in-the-path.aspx