# If a queryString can contain '.'

Tags: asp.net, web

If a queryString can contain a character `'.'`?

[For example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrDyj.jpg)

```
http://localhost:80/api/petstore/address/filter=address.id=100
```

In my memory it can not request to the correct host, so my old codes replace `'.'` to `'^'`,
and in the server replace `'^'` to `'.'`. The problem can't fix by encoding, because `'.'` will not
encode.

I just want to double check if queryString can contain a character `'.'`, and is there any better solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `.` is a safe URL character.

> A URL contains the name of the scheme being used (`<scheme>`) followed
>   by a colon and then a string (the `<scheme-specific-part>`) whose 
>   interpretation depends on the scheme.
>
> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters. The lower case letters "a"--"z", digits, and the characters plus ("+"), period ("."), and hyphen ("-") are allowed.

[source](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) and [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Your querystring, however does not look correct as you don't even have a `?`

`address/?filter=address.id=100` would mean the value of `filter` is `address.id=100`.

`address/?filter=address&id=100` would mean the value of `filter` is `address` and the value of `id` is `100`.

Coming up with your own encoding standards probably isn't the best idea.

If this is for routes and not querystring, then please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/1810243) about fix for period in routes. Although `.` is safe, it can cause problems in ASP.NET routes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I deploy a WEB-API project, and use routing rules so there is no ? character.

Comment: OK yes it is different in routing. So is the single value supposed to be `filter=address.id=100`?

Comment: @LewisZou `.` is safe but yes can cause issue in routes if you don't take steps to fix. I updated answer to link to another SO answer about periods in routes.

Comment: Great, the link you give me is what i want to ask! Thank you.