# Pass decimal as value in WebAPI 2 URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am creating a Web Api (v2.0) Method that needs to take in a decimal value as its parameter.

I am getting a 404 not found error if I use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4627/api/Product/Eligibility/10.5
```

But it works if I use the following URL against an Int parameter:

```
Http://localhost:4627/api/Product/Eligibility/10
```

These are the two corresponding Methods in the api:

```
// GET api/Product/Eligibility/10.0
[Route("api/Product/Eligibility/{amount:decimal}")]
public decimal GetEligibiilty(decimal amount)
{
    return amount;
}

// GET api/Product/Eligibility/10
[Route("api/Product/Eligibility/{amount:int}")]
public decimal GetEligibiilty(int amount)
{
    return amount;
}
```

Steve

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Got it working by adding a `"/"` to the end of the URL!

```
http://localhost:4627/api/Product/Eligibility/10.5/
```

Will find this method:

```
// GET api/Product/Eligibility/10.5/
[Route("api/Product/Eligibility/{amount:decimal}/")]
public decimal GetEligibiilty(decimal amount)
{
    return amount;
}
```

Steve

Comment: Related cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Comment: yes working for me but how it is running don't understand sir

Comment: Dude, you rock.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with passing a decimal in the URL, anyone using ASP.NET web pages here is a solution when redirecting after a transaction and the variable `amount` has a decimal in it:

```
Response.Redirect(@Href("~/Thankyou", amount + "/"));
```

The slash at the end of the URL is required to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem while working with Web API in Visual Studio 2015. I solved the problem by adding **?parameterName=decimalValue** at the end of the URL. In your case could be something similar to this:

http://localhost:4627/api/Product/Eligibility?amount=10.5

I hope can help.