# How to register a route that admits a dot in the path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to implement a routing system that admits a dot in the url. Currently I handle urls like:

mydomain/User/Details/raguilar

but if the username has a dot, then it is generated as:

mydomain/User/Details?username=r.aguilar

I tried to add the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Users",
            url: "User/{action}/{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", username = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { username = @"\w+\.?\w+" }
        );
```

and all seems to be ok, but when I clicked on the url I received an error that says that the related resource is not found or something like that.

Is there some way to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis) post. And [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/216044/Period-dot-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Route) on codeproject. I don't have access to VS so not able to try these out.

Comment: @Nilesh: Thanks, the first link helps me. I had looked for a question like that but I didn't find it.

Comment: That is great. You can answer your own question if you found the right solution. This might help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I should add the following line to the system.webServer/handlers element:

```
<add  name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" 
      path="/user/*" 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
      type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Where **user** is the controller to which belong the paths that will contain the dot.