# WebAPI OData can't deal with dots (i.e. '.') in a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a basic WebAPI OData application that seems to refuse to route requests to my controller if the parameter has a '.' in it.

For example:

http://localhost.com/vroot/odata/foo('abc') *<== routes correctly*

http://localhost.com/vroot/odata/foo('a.bc') *<== returns a 404 error*

I get the same 404 error even if I replace the '.' with a **%2E.**

http://localhost.com/vroot/odata/foo('a%2Ebc') *<== returns a 404 error*

Is this a generally understood problem in WebAPI OData?

Any ideas on what might be going on (or possibly how to work around this ?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dots in request urls are interpreted differently by IIS, so try adding the following setting in web.config:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

(From here: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html )

Some posts related to your issue:
[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: A perfect solution. It has been the same over the years