# Why MVC 5 does not call GetFile Method of my VirtualPathProvider Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to load Razor View from database.

I follow [ASP.NET MVC and virtual views](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) and [VirtualPathProvider in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237123/virtualpathprovider-in-mvc-5) to do that.

my Code :

VirtualPathProvider :

```
 public class DbPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
  {
    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        var page = FindPage(virtualPath);
        if (page == null)
        {
            return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        var page = FindPage(virtualPath);
        if (page == null)
        {
            return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return new DbVirtualFile(virtualPath, page.PageData.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private SiteModel FindPage(string virtualPath)
    {
        var db = new DatabaseContext();
        var page = db.SiteModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SiteName == virtualPath);
        return page;
    }
}
```

VirtualFile

```
public class DbVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    private byte[] data;

    public DbVirtualFile(string virtualPath, byte[] data)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public override System.IO.Stream Open()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(data);
    }
}
```

Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new DbPathProvider());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

Action :

```
public ActionResult Display(string id)
    {
        var db = new DatabaseContext();
        var site = db.SiteModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageName == id);
        if (site == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ViewBag.Body = site.PageContent;
        return View(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(site.SiteName));
    }
```

Data:

[image]

Case 1:

When virtualPath value is **"/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml"** then FileExists method return **true** and **GetFile method is called**.

Case 2:

When virtualPath value is **"~/Home/Display/ce28bbb6-03cb-4bf4-8820-373890396a90"** then FileExists method return **true** and **GetFile method and Display Action is never called.** and result is

*HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

I have no idea about dynamic view. I just read that two article and try to implement it.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

**I am using MVC 5 and .NET 4.5**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something I should be able to help you with.
There is something you are not thinking about which is ok, because I had loads of trouble with this too.

I think the issue you have here is knowing in what order everything fires.
This is what happens:

1. First the **VirtualPathProvider FileExists** method is called and
   this is where you are doing your magic to find the page. My methods are slightly different to yours, here is an example:

   ```
   public IList<Page> Pages
   {
       get
       {
           using (var uow = new UnitOfWork<SkipstoneContext>())
           {
               var companyService = new CompanyService(uow);
               var company = companyService.GetTenant();

               if (company != null)
               {
                   var pageService = new PageService(uow, company.Id);

                   return pageService.GetPublished();
               }
           }

           return null;
       }
   }

   public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
   {
       if (IsVirtualPath(virtualPath))
       {
           if (FindPage(virtualPath) != null)
           {
               var file = (PageVirtualFile)GetFile(virtualPath);
               return file.Exists;
           }
       }

       return Previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
   }

   public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
   {
       if (IsVirtualPath(virtualPath))
       {
           var page = FindPage(virtualPath);
           if (page != null)
           {
               var decodedString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(page.ViewData);
               var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decodedString);

               return new PageVirtualFile(virtualPath, bytes);
           }
       }

       return Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
   }

   public override System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
   {
       if (IsVirtualPath(virtualPath))
           return null;

       return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
   }

   public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
   {
       if (IsVirtualPath(virtualPath))
           return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

       return Previous.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
   }

   private Page FindPage(string virtualPath)
   {
       var virtualName = VirtualPathUtility.GetFileName(virtualPath);
       var virtualExtension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(virtualPath);

       try
       {
           if (Pages != null)
           {
               var id = Convert.ToInt32(virtualName.Replace(virtualExtension, ""));
               var page = Pages.Where(model => model.Id == id && model.Extension.Equals(virtualExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();

               return page;
           }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           // Do nothing
       }

       return null;
   }

   private bool IsVirtualPath(string virtualPath)
   {
       var path = (VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath) != "~/") ? VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath)) : VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(virtualPath);
       if (path.Equals("~/Views/Routing", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || path.Equals("/Views/Routing", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```
2. Now, if this page is served from the database it is a virtual page, so the next thing that happens is that it calls your **MvcHandler** (in my handler I have these functions)

   ```
   protected override IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
   {
       var vpp = new SkipstoneVirtualPathProvider(); // Create an instance of our VirtualPathProvider class
       var requestContext = ((MvcHandler)httpContext.Handler).RequestContext; // Get our request context
       var path = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // Get our requested path
       var pages = vpp.Pages; // Get all the published pages for this company

       if (pages != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) // If we have any pages and we have a path
       {
           var page = this.MatchPage(pages, path);
           if (page != null) // If we find the page
           {
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Routing"; // Set the controller
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index"; // And the action
           }
       }

       return base.BeginProcessRequest(httpContext, callback, state);
   }

   private Page MatchPage(IList<Page> pages, string path)
   {
       if (path == "/" || !path.EndsWith("/"))
       {
           var page = pages.Where(model => model.Path.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault(); // Try to match the path first
           if (page == null) // If we have no page, then get the directory and see if that matches any page
           {
               path = VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(path));
               page = pages.Where(model => model.Path.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
           }

           return page; // return our page or null if no page exists
       }

       return null; // return null if anything fails
   }
   ```
3. Just in case, when you create your MvcHandler if you have not already done so, it must be registered in **RouteConfig** like this:

   ```
       // default MVC route
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       ).RouteHandler = new SkipstoneRouteHandler();
   ```
4. In my **MvcHandler** I get my page and if it matches any virtual page I move to a **RoutingController**

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       using (var uow = new UnitOfWork<SkipstoneContext>())
       {
           var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
           var service = new PageService(uow, this.CompanyId);
           var userService = new UserService(uow, this.CompanyId);
           var user = userService.Get(userId);

           var fileName = service.View(Request.Url, user);

           if (!fileName.StartsWith(@"/") && !fileName.StartsWith("~/"))
               return View(fileName); // Show the page
           else
               return Redirect(fileName); // Redirect to our page
       }
   }
   ```

just for your sake I will show the **service.View** method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Views the CMS page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri">The current Request.Url</param>
    /// <param name="user">The current User</param>
    /// <returns>The filename of the requested page</returns>
    public string View(Uri uri, User user)
    {
        var path = uri.AbsolutePath; // Get our Requested Url
        var queryString = uri.Query;
        var pages = this.GetPublished();
        var page = pages.Where(model => model.Path.Equals(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault(); // Try to get the page

        if (page == null) // If our page is null
            page = pages.Where(model => model.Path.Equals(VirtualPathUtility.RemoveTrailingSlash(VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(path)))).SingleOrDefault(); // try to get the page based off the directory

        if (page == null) // If the page is still null, then it doesn't exist
            throw new HttpException(404, "This page has been deleted or removed."); // Throw the 404 error

        if (page.Restricted && user == null) // If our page is restricted and we are not logged in
            return "~/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=" + page.Path + queryString; // Redirect to the login page

        if (user != null && page.Restricted)
        {
            if (PageService.IsForbidden(page, user))
                throw new HttpException(401, "You do not have permission to view this page."); // Throw 401 error
        }

        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(page.Id.ToString());
    }
```

1. Then we are taken back to our **VirtualPathProvider** and the process begins again, but this time the virtual path will look something like this: **"~/Views/Routing/1331.aspx"**
2. If you notice, my **FindPage** method also looks for an extension match which I store in the database too: [image]
3. Then **GetFile** will be called and as long as you have followed my path, you should return the **VirtualFile**

I really hope that helps :)

Comment: Can you comment on why GetCacheDependency returns null, and why GetFileHash returns new Guid.NewGuid() ?

Comment: Sure, it is because I am disabling cache for items pulled from the database

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of time here... In my case it was also necessary to add `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` to the route configuration, otherwise '404 not found'.

Comment: @r3plica In this example what is SkipstoneRouteHandler()? what the definition it has?

Comment: Just my custom RouteHandler for handling sub-domains. It has no relevance to the solution :) you can actually just remove the `.RouteHandler = new SkipstoneRouteHandler()` and it will work

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue.
Razor view engine not call GetFile if you virtualPath is not *.cshtml format.
You need generate {Guid}.cshtml path format

Comment: that should not be the case. It will actually fire for all extension types.

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't be the case, but that is the same behavior I am seeing.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: ASP.NET 4 (MVC5) relative!

Despite the number of answers and a selected one, I will share my experience.

```
FileExists(string virtualPath)
```

gets called **twice**, once with a app relative path ("~/bla-bla") and once more with absolute one ("/bla-bla"). In my case the second one (the abs. path) fails. Seems like in ASP.NET 3 this was OK, however ASP.NET 4 (MVC5) checks it too. And requires it to return `true`. As a result

```
GetFile(string virtualPath)
```

doesn't get called.

For those who need to implement such behaviour `VirtualPathUtility` offers `ToAbsolute` and `ToAppRelative` convenience methods.

HTH