# Escaping Dot in Url gives 404

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using fiddler to test my application. When i pass http request including dot its returning 404.

Ex: `http://localhost:64052/api/getinfo/Mike%2Eporter`
I tried `http://localhost:64052/api/getinfo/Mike.porter`

But none of them works. My application is build on asp.net.
Please let me know if anybody has any idea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/handing-mvc-paths-with-dots-in-the-path)