# MVC action not getting called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have only 1 controller and have 1 action only in my example like this:

```
//
// GET: /Home/
public ActionResult Index(string source,string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

I have 2 routes registered for this action like -:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default2",
                url: "{source}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", source="source1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I call default, it calls `Index` action, which is OK
when I call like this, `/source1/12` - it works.

But when I call like this `/source1/12.0` - it does not work and shows up 404 ..

Can anyone suggest why is this happening ?

Comment: can you show the source action?

Comment: it is cause your action will be like

`public ActionResult Source(int id)`

Comment: public ActionResult Index(string source,string id)
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: the only difference is when I call like /sourceId/12 - it works but with   /sourceId/12.0 - it does not (12.0) does not , while /sourceid/12.0/ works (with / in last)

Comment: it may b because of the dot(.)

Comment: yes, but why ? 12.0.1 is also a string ?

Comment: What is the significance of the dot? This is most likely the answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/1795862

Comment: any idea how should I modify my action or route to get it working ?

Comment: for c# it might be a string but in the browser dot has a lot of more significance

Comment: check my answer it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably interpreting the .0 as a file extension, and thus looking for a file on disk.  Can you replace "." with "_" for the purposes of redirection, and replace back in your action method?  Otherwise, you have to look at ways you can get the routing not to interpret ".0" as a file extension.  Not sure exactly how off of the top of my head...

MVC routes errors like this to special methods.  One is in the controller: HandleUnknownAction, which is called when the action can't be matched.  You can override it and handle the action (logging it, etc.) there.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/) article, it has a solution for you:

From the link:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the ROuteCOnfig to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "{source}/{id}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Should solve your issue.

You can also check this **[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis/12151501#12151501)**