# Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS (Not Working in MVC 5)

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express, iis-8

Same question as in this link [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis) but like others doesnt work in mVC 5. What additional modifications needed to implement this in mvc 5. Thanks