# How to pass an IP address as a URL parameter to a Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

One of my Web API takes IP address as a URL param (string type) and does something with it. The problem is that I'm not able to pass an IP address as part of the URL.

It's a HTTP GET. A request of http://localhost/app/dosomethingwiththisip/10.20.128.0 fails while http://localhost/app/dosomethingwiththisip/10 succeeds (even though it fails in terms of what needs to be done with it).

Web API method is defined as, with attribute routing enabled,

```
[Route("dosomethingwiththisip/{ipAddress}")]
[HttpGet]
public bool dosomethingwiththisip(string ipAddress)
{
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How does the request with the IP fail? With what message?

Comment: It fails with a HTTP 404.

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Thanks @Pharylon for the tip. That helps; I'm going to go with a trailing slash. This proves that there is still room for improvements on the search domain :)

Comment: @Pharylon I still think this explicit question should be out there as the other question wasn't that explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I finally went with a simple solution of appending a slash character at the end of the URL after the IP address. Thanks to @Pharylon for the tip to a similar question, [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis/12151501#12151501)

Answer (score -2):

If you are specifying a url parameter and not a file or directory name, then you should prefix your list of parameters with ? so the web server knows. It can't tell what you intended.

Try: http://localhost/app/dosomethingwiththisip/?10.20.128.0

Comment: Thanks. A bit better but still an issue with route resolution I guess, {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/app/users/dosomethingwiththisip/?10.20.128.0'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'users'."}

Comment: Please learn about ASP.NET MVC's and WebAPI's routing (or URL rewriting/routing in general).

Comment: URL rewrites are still based on URLS. Broken trickery doesn't change that the webserver was trying to load a page called 10.20.128.0