# Using '.' in Web Api using Attribute Routing is giving 404 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I am using Routing Attribute to try to send a string via url to my web Api.
I have a Route defined as

```
[Route("Search/{searchText}")]
```

I am expecting a string value as searchText. It seems to be working fine but I am getting an error if there is a '.' in my parameter. 
For ex.

```
http://localhost/api/Person/Search/me is working fine,
```

but

```
http://localhost/api/Person/Search/me.me
```

is throwing a 404 error in my browser.

The '.' character ir working fine using conventional routing

```
http://localhost/api/Person?q=me.me
```

I am getting the error only is case of attribute routing.
I have been following this article on attribute routing for all references - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2.
How to use attribute routing for sending '.' character as a part of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your Web.config in the `<system.WebServer><handlers>...</handlers></system.WebServer>`section:

`<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/Search/*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

Thread I used to solve this same problem: [1]: [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Edit: If you need to do this for multiple routes, you'll probably have to do `/*/*` for path.