# can i pass dot as parameter to id in controller method in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am new to MVC and working on view having list of users and by selection on userid details should display on the screen...
getting Error on selection of id like 'abc.xyx' .. is doing some wrong...

Error while select id field contains '.' Dot in it
 Example : xyz.abc

View

links

```
 <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.vUserID  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.vUserID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.vUserID  })
    </td>
```

Controller

```
    // Error :  /User/Details/xyz.abc
    // no Error: /User/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        try
        {

            tblUserMaster tblusermaster = db.tblUserMasters.Find(id);
            if (tblusermaster == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tblusermaster);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Error on : localhost:9467/User/Details/dave.schneider
Error message is

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: is it working fine with "zyxabc"? ..without dot?

Comment: Yes shekhar,... its wotking fine when id is zyxabc ... like ..

Comment: hi michael, error is HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. and not able to debug it.

Comment: you should not allow user to enter that with dot

Comment: hi Ehsan, yes i will but in such a case what we should try ? its accepting '-' keyword but not '.' (Dot)

Comment: what route you use? are you sure that not go into `Details` action and just get `if (tblusermaster == null)`?

Comment: hi, Grundy... i had debug it in normal case it display details page successfully ... but in this case of Dot(.) shows error..

Comment: so, with do you go into action? or not? also can you provide your `route`?

Comment: No .. unable to go action while debugging in (.) Dot case . and my route is http://localhost:9467/User/Details/dave.schneider

Comment: Yes i am posted its in Question window .

Comment: Hi, there seems to be a similar question here with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Comment: hi Ric,  Yes Its works .... thanks for the share that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes solve it by 
Change In Web.config File  section and add

`<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

In the system.web section of your web.config(.net 4)

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Comment: i tried but still having same error...  i set in web config .. <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />