# Can't find the registered route in MVC app. What is missing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC 4 app. I added a simple controller Get method that I am trying to call. I always get 404 error when I try to load the page.

HTML page that calls the method - **demo.html** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="/vdo/?id=small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class VdoController : ApiController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        .....

        HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
        .....

        return resp;
    }         
}
```

Route Registration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
      context.MapRoute(
                "Vdo",
                "vdo/{id}",
                new { controller = "Vdo" },
                new string[] { "<Namespace>.Controllers" }
            );    
}
```

**What am I missing?**

Here is what I see in browser:
[image]

**Here is the actual error I just got in debug mode:**

*The controller for path '/vdo/small.mp4' was not found or does not implement IController.*

Answer (score 0):

when we use routing we don't need to use querystring to pass data in the url. i think your problem in your url, you written your route rule like-
`vdo/{id}` but you are requesting for the controller function using querystring, you should change your url to-`/vdo/small.mp4` from `/vdo/?id=small.mp4`
i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to map a default action to Get

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
          context.MapRoute(
                    "Vdo",
                    "vdo/{id}",
                    new { controller = "Vdo", action = "Get" },
                    new string[] { "<Namespace>.Controllers" }
                );    
    }
```

Then you can use `/vdo/small.mp4` to access it.

Comment: No difference. The actual error is still - "The controller for path '/vdo/small.mp4' was not found or does not implement IController."

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis , it seems your issue is the Handler not knowing what to do with the period in the id parameter.

Comment: No. If I take out the the dot, it still has same issue.

Comment: Can you try changing the Base Class to Controller instead of ApiContoller?

Comment: That gives other issues. Some part of the code will not compile.

Comment: Maybe implement what [this guy](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/) did and see if it solves your problem. Also, ignore what I suggested in my answer about defining the default action as it is unnecessary.