# MVC - Can I expose action methods with URL extensions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I do the following?

I want a user to browse to `https://localhost/Registration/GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer.wav` and have it run the action of `GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer` on the `Registration` controller, which serves an `audio/wav` file.

What works for me right now is browsing to `https://localhost/Registration/GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer`

But what do I need to do to make `https://localhost/Registration/GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer.wav` route to the same action? Is there a way in MVC to specify action routes for something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of a spinoff, but I was able to instead get `https://localhost/Registration/GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer/clip.wav` routing to my `GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer` action.

Two simple changes:

1) Add this route to your action:

```
[Route("clip.wav")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer()
```

2) Add this handler into your `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer><handlers><add name="Wave File Handler" path="clip.wav" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS (7+) to do this, basically:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Wav Files" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Registration/?(.*)\.wav$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/Registration/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

That will strip off the extension and send it to the controller. It's rewritten so it should still present as *Registration/GetCaptchaAudioInternetExplorer.wav* in the browser.

---

Potentially you can try setting [relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

But with .wav being a real thing, I'm not sure if that will work. More detail on [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/).

---

A final alternative you can [enable RAMMFAR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx):

> RAMMFAR means "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" and refers to this
>   optional setting in your web.config.

```
 <system.webServer>   
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />    
 </system.webServer>
```

That should send all requests through MVC regardless of extension. I say final, as this has a performance hit.

Comment: I can't use IIS rules because they are not guaranteed to be there :( I thought there would be a way of doing this with MVC routes, no??? http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Thanks for the ideas...I found a bit of a workaround myself while researching; please check out my answer when I post it.