# How to get all path and query string in MVC or WebAPI Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, url-routing

I have a need to get everything after "/proxy" in my web application. Here are some example URLS:

```
/proxy/HU91r//www.dde3.xhyzlkejkeje.3322.es/es/px
/proxy/7ZROK?si=0&e=http%3A%2F%2Fsecdd-uat.clsssapp
/proxy/someapp.js?_t=something&_r=bla.html&_a=s&_n=39393
```

How do I get everything after "/proxy"?
I tried doing this:

```
[Route("proxy/*")]
public string Get() {
  // do stuff with request here..
}
```

But that didn't work. It's like the "`*`" isn't being honored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a argument to take the value after proxy. The QueryString will not be part of the route. For sample:

```
[Route("proxy/{*argument}")]
public string Get(string argument) 
{
   // code
}
```

Make sure you have setted the `*` to take everything.

Comment: But that starts to fall apart when the stuff following "/proxy" contains "/" slashes, like the first example URL in the question.

Comment: That works for the first 2 URLs in my example, but I just added a 3rd one that contains a period "." and that isn't matching the pattern.

Comment: Maybe it is a MVC issue, take a look at it and see how many different ways you can solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Comment: Yep that SO link you provided (along with the pattern you suggested) did seem to do the trick. Thanks Felipe!