# mvc5 HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found with details ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.WarehouseID })
```

It gives me this link `http://localhost:6587/WareHouse/Details/1.00000000`

The Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(decimal? id)
{
    Warehouse Warehouse = db.Warehouse.Find(id);
    return View(Warehouse);
}
```

when I change the action link to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { WareHouseID = item.WarehouseID })
```

And retrieve the link as queryString it works well

```
public ActionResult Details(decimal? WareHouseID) 
{
    Warehouse Warehouse = db.Warehouse.Find(WareHouseID);
    return View(Warehouse);
}
```

But as id it gives me

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

I tried to trace it by debugging
but it not step into details actionResult with that link
`http://localhost:6587/WareHouse/Details/1.00000000`

my route config

```
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace TestErp
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You not seriously using a `decimal` as an identifier/key are you?

Comment: yes I am using decimal ,, no problem with duplicates of dots but it is because of dots .   The link that you  putt is really helpful ,, I found that if I put trailling slash it works well ,  
that is because without the trailing slash, IIS thinks it is a file that it should go and find. Adding the slash has the effect of...this is not a real file... so I am trying now to do some thing about that , thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It is because of dots .  I found that if I put trailling slash it works well , that is because without the trailing slash, IIS thinks it is a file that it should go and find. Adding the slash has the effect of...this is not a real file... so I am trying now to do some thing about that .

The details 
[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)