# Asp.net Web API Attribute Routing does not work with "."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, attributerouting

Attribute Routing with a "." is not working in my Web API project
Sample URL which does not work

> http://localhost:8082/image/TestImage.jpg

```
   [RoutePrefix("image")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("{uuid}.{extension}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri(Name = "uuid")] string uuid,
            [FromUri(Name = "extension")] string extension)
        {
            // Not coming here with the URL http://localhost:8082/image/TestImage.jpg

        }
    }
```

If I remove the . and the extension then it works. So, this works...

> http://localhost:8082/image/TestImage

```
[RoutePrefix("image")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{uuid}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri(Name = "uuid")] string uuid//,
        //[FromUri(Name = "extension")] string extension)
    {
        // Works with the URL http://localhost:8082/image/TestImage

    }
}
```

I am using IIS Express locally.

Comment: Are you running on IIS? If so, Static File handlers might get in your way

Comment: @PeterLillevold, yes I am using IIS Express. I have edited my question. Any solution?

Comment: Try editing the how the site deals with HTTP handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Comment: @DavidOesterreich, please enter is an answer so that I can accept it. the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests did the trick.