# Period in URL segment causes 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, iis-express

I have a custom route:

```vb
<Route("maintenance/test/{one}/{two}/{three}")>
Function Test(ByVal one As String, ByVal two As String, ByVal three As String) As JsonResult
    Return Json(True, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

When I hit the route it works as expected:

> localhost:1337/maintenance/test/1/2/3

However, if any of the parameters contains a period, such as:

> localhost:1337/maintenance/test/1/2./3      <sup>(note period after 2)</sup>

I get a 404 "The resource cannot be found" error.

It seems IIS is picking up the URL and trying to serve a static file instead of passing it onto MVC.

Things I've tried (to no avail):

- Adding a trailing slash to force IIS to recognize it as a URL and not a resource
- Adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to web.config's `<system.webServer><modules>` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064424/118697).
- Adding a TransferRequestHandler handler as per [this answer]:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/118697)

```xml
    <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" 
         path="/people/*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
         type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

- Updating MVC 5 to the latest (5.2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original assumption that IIS was treating the request as a resource request was incorrect.

It turns out ASP.NET blocks any request for a URL with a `./` in the same way it blocks legacy reserved words.

The solution then is to enable `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping`:

```xml
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Sources:

- Haacked - [Allowing reserved filenames in URLs](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730036/118697) on SO (despite the fact that the comments say it doesn't work with MVC 5)