# How can I add .htm at the end of URL in when using attribute routing in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
 [Route("{page?}/{category?}/{detail?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string page, string category, string detail)
    {
        navigation _nav = nav.GetItemByALias(MODULE_CODE, page, "vn");
        ViewBag.template = _nav.template_code;
        ViewBag.page = page;
        ViewBag.category = category;
        ViewBag.detail = detail;
        ViewBag.lang = "vn";
        if(_nav.template_code == "goldencity_news" && detail  != null && detail != "")
        {
            ViewBag.template = _nav.template_code + "_detail";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Normally.

- `local:port`
- `local:port/home`
- `local:port/page/category`
- `local:port/page/category/detail`

All above is right

But, when I change **(add .htm at Route config)**

```
 [Route("{page?}/{category?}/{detail?}.htm")]
    public ActionResult Index(string page, string category, string detail)
    {
        navigation _nav = nav.GetItemByALias(MODULE_CODE, page, "vn");
        ViewBag.template = _nav.template_code;
        ViewBag.page = page;
        ViewBag.category = category;
        ViewBag.detail = detail;
        ViewBag.lang = "vn";
        if(_nav.template_code == "goldencity_news" && detail  != null && detail != "")
        {
            ViewBag.template = _nav.template_code + "_detail";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

only one case right:

- `local:port/page/category/detail.htm`.

This list below I need:

- `Local:port`
- `Local:port/page`
- `Local:port/page.htm`
- `local:port/page/category`
- `local:port/page/category.htm`
- `local:port/page/category/detail`
- `local:port/page/category/detail.htm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: Thank you.. I will recheck.