# ASP.NET - Getting 404 Error while using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I've run into an error 404, which implicates that I lack certain resource.

I'm unexperienced with ASP.NET MVC really and routing is the where I suck most, though this is unexcpected error for me as I have the required controller + action.

1 Raport has many ThrashType records. They are seperate tables, though it doesn't matter at this point I think.

The problem is that I get the correct view and records of Raport table.

When I hover link in the view it has format {host}/Raport/EditRecords/{string_id}

When I click the link in the view (trying to go to EditRecords) I get 404 error which is confusing atm.

```
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {                  
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "Edit/{productId}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Edit" },
            new { productId = @"\w+" }
            );
        }
```

Code is as follows:

controller EditRaport:

```
    public ActionResult EditRaport()
    {
       var query = from dbs in db.Raport
                    select dbs;

        return View(query as IEnumerable<Raport>);
    }
```

controller EditRecords:

```
     public ActionResult EditRecords(string id)
    {
        var query = from dbs in db.ThrashType
                    where dbs.raport_id == id
                    select dbs;

        return View(query as IEnumerable<ThrashType>);
    }
```

view for EditRaport:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Klasy_Raport.Raport>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditRaport";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Raport</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserFrontInfo.userName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.creation_time)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.last_modyfication)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserFrontInfo.userName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.creation_time)
        </td>       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.last_modyfication)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRecords", new { id=item.raport_id }) 

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Could you possibly give me a clue about where the error might be? I really don't understand 404 in this case.

**EDIT 15:37 13.09.2016**

With help from @StephenMuecke I learned what the cause of the problem was.
He gave me a link which explains the problem in more detail:
[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

In fact my ID was sth like "12.34.56 00:00:00abcde". If you try to do it it causes IE error (404).

The answer is to change the ID into sth like "1234560000000abcde" which makes it ok for IE to proccess.

In my case this did the job:

```
    //remove dots and colons from string
    var datePart = DateTime.Today.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(":","");

    //giving string properties and assigning for alias
    var namePart = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

    //removing @blablabl.ab - 12 signs, 13 is for the sake of correct      indexing
    var nameShort = namePart.Remove((namePart.Length)-13, 12);

    //final ID concatenation
    newRaport.raport_id = datePart + nameShort;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a View for `EditRecords`?

Comment: EditRecords action - is it the part of Raport controller?

Comment: So the you have an action EditRecords in the controller EditRecordsController or what's the name of the controller?

Comment: Not related but you 2nd route is pointless - it can never be hit unless its placed before the default route (the order of routes is important)

Comment: Are both those methods in `RaportController`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke to 1st comment: yeah I know , though thx for pointing this out, it's a leftover :) 2nd: yeh they are

Comment: @Hypnobrew all are in RaportController

Comment: @JamesP yes I do :)

Comment: @Andrei yes it is

Comment: The code as shown will work fine. Do you have any other route definitions?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no other routes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123254/discussion-between-aleksander-dudek-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: I think I ran into that before. As ridiculous as it may sound, try to rename `id` into something, say `recordId`, in both route and action method

Comment: @Andrei actually Stephen helped me with this, the problem was that primary key that contains special signs (in my case dots, space and colons) I changed it and now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {                  
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "Edit/{productId}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Edit" },
        new { productId = @"\w+" }
        );
    }
```

Remove the following routing in RegisterRoutes :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "Edit/{productId}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Edit" },
        new { productId = @"\w+" }
        );
```