# MVC routing does not accept dot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method in my Web API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/chart({param})")]
public IHttpActionResult TimesheetChart(string param) 
{
  // do something
}

GetStringAsync("/chart(1)") - works
GetStringAsync("/chart(1.test)") - does not work
GetStringAsync("/chart(1test)") - works
```

seems like the dot causes it not to work. I also tried URL encoding the dot with %2E but it still does not work.

Can anyone please tell me how make this work with special characters. The data to be passed in param is supposed to be something like this.

```
/chart("http://test.domain.com,john.doe@someemail.com,status")
```

but i'm having trouble with the dot how much more the whole thing.

Thanks,

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11728846/3465753) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding following setting in your web.config file should fix your issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```