# jQuery Ajax POST - 404 error because of strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

This question makes me puzzled, the post works well on my local server.After I deploy to the server, it works for normal strings.
And if there are strings like **xxx.xx**, error POST 404 will be reported in the server online environment, but the local does not have this problem.

the javascript:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#submit-quesAnswer').click(function(){
        _qu.answerContent = _qu.ed.input.val();
        if(!_qu.answerContent || _qu.answerContent.length<10){
            _dialogBox({title:'提示',message:'Thanks for your help! But please answer at least 10 strings.'});return false;
        }

        $('#submit-quesAnswer').attr('disabled','true').html('Processing');
        submitAnswer();
    });
});

function submitAnswer(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',url:"/lib/php/question/answer.php",
        data:{
            action:'submit',qid:_qu.id,content:_qu.answerContent
        }
    }).done(function(str){
        $('#submit-quesAnswer').removeAttr('disabled').html('提交回答');
        let resp;
        try{resp = JSON.parse(str);} catch(err){
            _dialogBox({title:'出错啦！',message:str});return;
        }

        if(resp.status=='success'){
            $('#submit-quesAnswer').attr('disabled','true').html('提交成功');
            gxz.storage.remove(_qu.ed.autoSave.name);

            _dialogBox({
                title:'回答提交成功啦！',message:"<p>感谢你的无私帮助！小蔗将在 5 秒内为你进行跳转。</p>",
                yes:function(){window.location.reload();}
            });
            setTimeout(()=>{window.location.reload();},5000);
        } else {
            _dialogBox({title:'提交失败: '+resp.status,message:resp.reason});
        }
    });
}
```

the example error data: (_qu.answerContent)

```
data modify block ~ 255 ~ Items[0].id set from entity @s SelectedItem.id
data modify block ~ 255 ~ Items[0].tag set from entity @s SelectedItem.tag
```

Hoever,this data is fine:

```
data modify block ~ 255 ~ Items[0].id set from entity @s SelectedItem.id
```

Online server report an error like: `jquery.min.js:2 POST https://www.mcadmin.cn/lib/php/question/answer.php 404 (Not Found)`

So, why does this string only cause the server to report an error?

Comment: where is `_qu` ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut just a global variable for easy modification, it's no problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Period in query string parameter breaks Aurelia routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342821/period-in-query-string-parameter-breaks-aurelia-routes)