# ASP.Net MVC Allows Explicit Routing to Specific File Having Dot in the Folder Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an `ASP.Net MVC` application run on `IIS`. Is it possible to let the client to directly access certain file in the folder without going through normal (`Controller-Action-View`) process?

Say, I have the domain name: `www.example.com` and the file path is `~/.Sample/SubFolder/Filename` (note the dot `'.'` before `Sample`) relative to `www.example.com`

Now, without the dot `'.'`, you can create a `Controller` named `Sample` and an `Action` named `SubFolder` which takes argument `Filename` and returns the `SubFolder View` in the `Views` folder. But this folder is having a dot.

So, I want the application to directly show the `Filename` content by writing

```
www.example.com/.Sample/SubFolder/Filename
```

When I already put the file `Filename` in the `.Sample/SubFolder` folder relative to `www.example.com` and tried accessing it by writing `www.example.com/Sample/Filename`, the following error is shown:

> Server Error
>
> 404 - File or directory not found.
>
> The resource you are
>   looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

Any idea? A solution using `IIS` is acceptable.

Comment: You can create a controller method in the `SampleController` and then create a specific route for it that omits the action name, so `/Sample/someFileName` routes to `publicActionResult XXX(string fileName)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is what I will normally do... But the `Sample` is not really `Sample` it is in fact having a dot in front: `.Sample` -> this cannot be done by normal controller method, no?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis) for info on handling the `dot`, but I don't understand what your mean by `/.Sample/Filename` (where does the dot come from? and is `.Sample` the folder name?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, `.Sample` is a folder name directly under the root directory of the MVC application

Comment: In a typical (traditional?) web page, you can put a folder under the root folder having `.` and when people want to open a file under it, they can simply do `www.root.com/.Sample/somefileinthefolder` (note that the dot is in the **folder** name) -> basically I want to do this for a specific file in `ASP.Net MVC` application

Comment: refer http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved in the `IIS` by choosing the specific folder we want to allow `Directory Browsing` on.

By default `IIS` would disable the `Directory Browsing` feature on **all** folders. To enable the directory browsing for specific folder, select the folder in the `IIS Connections -> Server Name -> Web site name -> Folder name` as shown below:

[image]

In the `Feature View` of the specified folder, select the `IIS -> Directory Browsing` feature:

[image]

Then you simply need to enable the feature for the specific folder:

[image]

And now we can conveniently browse the folder:

[image]