# Dots in URL causes 404 with Web API call in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a similar requirement which is mentioned in the link  [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis) . Our requirement is, we also do have URLs with dots in the path. For example I may have a URL such as www.example.com/people/michael.phelps (This example is taken from above link)
URLs with the dot generate a 404. If we pass without the dot, then everything works. If we add the dot I get a 404 error.

The above link provide solution for earlier versions of .net where we can have webconfig files. But we are using .net core to build web API application. Dotnet core does not support webconfig files. Can someone please suggest how can we arrive at the solution by using .net core.

Comment: share how your routing is configured. Simple routing like `[HttpGet("/before.after")]` works fine for me.

Comment: Do not forget to append trailing slash like www.example.com/people/michael.phelps/, it should work

Comment: We use attribute routing. before.after will not work for us as we do not have idea on how many dots are present in the path. For example, dit.web.config

Comment: Show an example of the attribute route that fails?

Comment: This is how we have defined our method in API controller [Route("~/api/HierarchyProperty/store/{store}/hierarchy/{*hierarchy}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetByName(string store, string hierarchy)
        {
            return this.hierRep.Get(store, hierarchy);
        }

Comment: We are calling api as below http://localhost:65135/api/HierarchyProperty/store/xyz/hierarchy/dit.web.config

Comment: We are calling api as below and it returns 404 error http://localhost:65135/api/HierarchyProperty/store/xyz/hierarchy/dit.web.config                                                                                                                                          However, if we call without any dots in between it succeeds. For eg: http://localhost:65135/api/HierarchyProperty/store/xyz/hierarchy/ditwebconfig

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but we had a similar case:

We had a url looking like https:/domain.com/somepath/smoething.cd

This returned a 404 from the IIS. Adding a / at the end of the url behind the .cd fixed the issue.

Strange but notable: not all.something return a 404, .com at the end of the path for example works

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed this kind of problem. Adding a / at the end is a workaround. 

Since I'm using Kestrel, it doesn't seem to be an IIS Issue, also I'd like to notice, that it just doesn't match the route, but middleware after routing will still be executed.