# Can Asp.Net MVC ScriptBundle output filename not contain a dot?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, bundle

Currently in my BundleConfig.cs I have this:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/widgets.js").Include(
            "~/scripts/widget.one.js",
            "~/scripts/widget.two.js",
            "~/scripts/widget.three.js"
        )
```

But I get a 404 when the page tries to load the JS asset. If I change the virtual filename back to "~/bundles/widgetsjs" then it works fine again.

Im interested to know in case I have understood this incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)