# MVC Specify Actions with Querystring Params instead of "/" folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

In MVC6, is there a way to specify the actions in my URL to be querystrings instead of a path?

E.G. http://localhost/Index2 and http://localhost/Edit

Both of these fire the Index2 and Edit actions in my controller respectively. But I'm working with a web site where we're only allows to have one single URL (long story)... so it it possible to fire the exact same actions by navigating to respective urls like

http://localhost/Default.aspx?action=Index2 and http://localhost/Default.aspx?action=Edit

I suppose what I could do is just take the dozen or so action functions in my controller and combine them ALL into the Index action and based on the "action" querystring parameter, do a switch/case-select statement and copy each of the original action/subs into their respective chunks under each CASE. But I was hoping there would be something could be done that seemed a little cleaner.

FYI: I don't use querystrings for anything else. All my values are passed from action to action by POSTS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the `Route` decorator but instead of adding a route string, you add an empty string. Example:

```
namespace TestAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/testapi")] // eg: http://localhost/api/testapi?param1=foo&param2=bar
    public class TestAPIController : BaseAPIController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")] // so that ASP MVC recognizes query strings
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {

            // get the query parameters into a collection
            var queryparams = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Select(q => new { q.Key, q.Value });


            // declare main keys value pairs
            string param1 = queryparams.Where(k => k.Key == "param1").Select(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            string param2 = queryparams.Where(k => k.Key == "param2").Select(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            // Do your stuff

            // Return a response


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since my actions currently are accepting parameters via post and you have the [HttpGet] attribute up there, would this still work? In order to continue recceiving the posted fields I'd have to change your example to [HttpPost] (while still collecting the querystring to get the action name)

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't see that. Yes changing it to `[HttpPost]` should work. I thing you also need to change the method invocation to something like `public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]param1 value)`

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is pretty easy to do by subclassing `RouteBase`. It allows you to use virtually any logic you want to analyze the request and direct it to specific action methods depending on whats in the request.

Here is a route using your example of http://localhost/Default.aspx?action=Index2 and http://localhost/Default.aspx?action=Edit

```
public class CustomRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData result = null;

        // Trim off the leading "/"
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path.Substring(1);

        if (path.Equals("Default.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());

            result.Values["controller"] = "Home";
            result.Values["action"] = httpContext.Request.QueryString["action"] ?? "Index";
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Returning null tells the routing framework to try
        // the next registered route.
        return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // Returning null skips this route.
        // Alternatively, implement a scheme to turn the values passed here
        // into a URL. This will be used by UrlHelper to build URLs in views.
        return null;
    }
}
```

It can be registered with MVC like this.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.Add(new CustomRoute());

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "WebApplication23.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Do note that the order routes are registered is important.

There is one more thing if you insist on using a `filename.extension` pattern - you have to configure IIS to allow the request to reach MVC because by default [any URL with a `.` in it will throw a 404 not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/181087).

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
      path="/Default.aspx"
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
      type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Actually the ".aspx" isn't required. I just threw it in there arbitrarily. I'll give it a shot