# Web api routing fails in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a asp.net MVC 5 project with lots of controllers and web apis. The problem is when i want to access one of the api methods, i get **No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI ...** error.

I tried every solution in similar posts but i wasn't lucky. 
This is my RouteConfig file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Routing configs
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Files api routs
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "filesApi_1",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{file}",
        defaults: new object[]
        {
            new { controller = "Files", action ="SaveAttachment"}
        }
     );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "filesApi_2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{fileName}",
    defaults:
        new { controller = "Files", action = "DeleteAttachment" }
    );
}
```

When i go to htt://localhost:xxxx/api/Files/DeleteAttachment/file_name, i get the error.

My Global.asax.cs is:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); 
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Mapper.Initialize(c=> c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
    }
```

The controller is:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    public void SaveAttachment(HttpPostedFileBase file){}
    public void DeleteAttachment(string fileName){}
}
```

It is very strange that if i add attribute routing for web api actions, they work as expected. For example:

```
[Route("api/Files/DeleteAttachment/{fileName}")]
public void DeleteAttachment(string fileName){}
```

I don't want write Route for every action because i have lots of actions and it make the code fragile. How can i fix routing in the route table? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tag your Api controller methods with attributes `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` so the routing mechanism will know when to use each.

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveAttachment(HttpPostedFileBase file){}
    [HttpGet]
    public void DeleteAttachment(string fileName){}
}
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
And the second issue may be with your default routing values:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "filesApi_2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{fileName}",
    defaults:
        new { controller = "Files", action = "DeleteAttachment" }
    );
```

There is `fileName` parameter missing in default route, so change it to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "filesApi_2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{fileName}",
    defaults:
        new { controller = "Files", action = "DeleteAttachment", fileName = "" }
    );
```

or

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "filesApi_2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{fileName}",
    defaults:
        new { controller = "Files", action = "DeleteAttachment", fileName = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ok, if it is still not working than it is due to file_name containing `.`. Web api routing doesn't like dot characters in last parameter. 
 Change your URL from `http://localhost:58893/api/files/deleteattachment/file.jpg` 
 to 
`http://localhost:58893/api/files/deleteattachment/file.jpg/`
 and you should be able to invoke requested method

Comment: I updated answer according your comment with file_name

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the file name. If the file url is coming or the value in filename contain '/' it will split the route and create a new url as

`htt://localhost:xxxx/api/Files/DeleteAttachment/file_name_before_slash/file_name_after_slash`

It will not match your URL.

Check value in file name part of your code.

**-------------------  Edit 1 ------------------------------------**

The problem may be in filename "file.jpg". The dot (.) in the file name causes the issue [refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis), more similar questions are available. [Also check this one](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/).

try

```
 <configuration>
     <system.web>
         <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

          <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
     </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: when there is not '/' in the file name, i can't reach the action too.

Comment: @ehsantoghian can you provide some more details about the error. like complete error message or stack trace.

Comment: The complete error is: `{ "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58893/api/files/deleteattachment/file.jpg'.", "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Files' that matches the request." `

Comment: @ehsantoghian the problem is in filename  "file.jpg" the (.) in the file name causes the issue [reffer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis), more similar questions are available. [Also check this one](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/)

Comment: i fixed the dot (.) in the file name, but for the brevity didn't mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

Convention routing follows template based routing that you configure in webApiConfig but Attribute routing is a lot more flexible. I agree that you may not want to write [Route] attribute over every method but later provides a lot of flexibility.

In one of my project, I could use the same controller to have different route APIs serving similar functionality and as asked by UI development team.[Refer this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)