# Implementing Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to get a handle on attribute routing in MVC.

Initially, the routing for my sitemap controller was as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SitemapXml",
            url: "sitemap.xml",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sitemap", action = "Index" }

        // Additional mappings...

    }
}
```

That works fine. But then I tried commenting out the `SitemapXml` routing above and instead adding an attribute in my controller.

```
// GET: Sitemap
[Route("sitemap.xml")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Generate sitemap
}
```

I also added the following line at the end of `RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

But now when I navigate to domain.com/sitemap.xml, I get a page not found error.

Questions:

1. What steps am I missing to get my routing attribute to work?
2. Since mappings can now be specified in two places (as attributes or set directly in the `RouteCollection`), what happens when those two places contradict each other?

Comment: It is the `.` in the URL. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis ?

Comment: @Shyju: I didn't see that. Thanks, I didn't realize the dot causes problems. Looks like the workaround isn't that great either. Guess I'll just go back to setting that in `RegisterRoutes`. (It doesn't appear to have any problem with dots.)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the extension .xml , your attribute routing will work perfectly. And its better to use the extension related code in action method.

Also make sure your route config looke like (routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); should exist before default route)

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```