# rest api can't receive encoded parameters in urls

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

We have some endpoints that receive a username, the username may contain special characters, for example:
POST /api/users/{userName}/cars/

if the username is "joe+doe", then we have a 404 error, we have enconded and send
POST /api/users/joe%2Bdoe/cars/

Still it doesn't work

We could either change to an id or change it into a format like "api/users/cars?username={username}" but we would like to follow the logic we have.

So the question is "is there a way to configure endpoints in rest api to accepts encoded chars"

Comment: You could encode the username in base 64 and in server side decode it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: Please share your routing configuration with us.  An [mcve] would be preferred.