# passing url parameter string with + sign to asp .net core server endpoint fails

Tags: .net

I need to send a query parameter string with + sign to an endpoint. The endpoint url looks like this.

http://localhost:55917/api/abc/files/getFileDownloadLink/a%2Bb.pdf/9846.pdf

Here I am trying to get download link by passing fileName and urlKey. Both are string values. In the above example filename would be a%2Bb.pdf (url encoded name) and url key is 9846.pdf.The issue is when I try to download a file that contains a + sign in its name the get request fails. The request fails before entering the controller which means it fails before mapping the values to the controller parameters. But if I request a filename without plus sign it works.

Controller is implemented as below,

```
[HttpGet("GetFileDownloadLink/{fileName}/{urlKey}")]
public IActionResult GetFileDownloadLink(string fileName, string 
urlKey)
{
   return Ok(fileService.GetDownloadLink(fileName, urlKey));
}
```

I found that the plus sign needs to be encoded to %2B but it still did not work. Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: What do you mean the request fails? Does the server return an HTTP 500 status?

Comment: @john Wu It did not show any status code explicitly. It just said CORS error. But as I researched more about that I found that the underling issue is not a CORS error but some other error is causing it to show as CORS error. If I do find the status code though I will update this thread.

Answer (score -1):

To me the problem seems to be in the way you are passing Query Parameters.
Below are the links that can help you.

ASP.NET MVC: [ASP.NET MVC - Getting QueryString values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values)

ASP.NET Core:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

The dot in url parameter hope this link helps: [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: I have updated the description with .net code. It seems fine to me. Also when a send a file name without a + sign it works. So I think it's not an issue with the endpoint.

Comment: Hope this link helps it should be a dot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137462/file-name-with-extension-in-url-as-a-parameter

Comment: That also cannot be the issue because if I request a file without the plus sign it works even when the filename contains a dot.