# c# append slash to the path parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add `dot (.)` in path parameter and it turns out that dot will only work if we append a `/` slash at the end of that parameter.

For example: `/api/path.param/?q=123`  this will work

However: `/api/path.param?q=123`    wont work without the trailing slash

I was hoping to programmatically add the `slash /` if the query parameter is `q=123`.

How can this be done in `MVC 4`?

Comment: You can use a dot in the path without adding a `\`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `/api/path.param` is always the same you could use (the hack-y method):

```
variable_name = variable_name.Substring(0, 15) + "/" + variable_name.Substring(15);
```

If it isn't always the same you could do (the more dynamic method):

```
int index = variable_name.IndexOf("?q=");
variable_name = variable_name.Substring(0, index) + "/" + variable_name.Substring(index);
```

Comment: where is this added, controller, route config? can you show that

Comment: Well I need more context to the way that your script works, this code would go after the `/api/path.param?q=123` is formed but before it is used.

Comment: assuming that to be the controller, it is not even reaching controller

Comment: This is a pathstring submitted to the app, the fail occurs before code that responds to the pathstring even is invoked.  This Answer needs clarity on where the pathstring update could occur.