# How to get ASP.NET MVC to match dot (".") character at the end in a route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC treats dot character as a literal for routes [for a long time](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx). However it doesn't match the route if the dot is at the end of the given route part.

Given the route `{controller}/{action}/{id}` MVC matches these:

```
http://test/somecontroller/someaction/some.id
http://test/somecontroller/someaction/....some.id
```

But not these:

```
http://test/somecontroller/someaction/someid.
http://test/somecontroller/someaction/someid...
```

My requirement is to have arbitrary number of dots anywhere in the id section. Is there a way to work this around or is it a known situation that we need to avoid? It seems to me an MVC 2 bug.

P.S. You can also reproduce the same behavior on StackOverflow by adding dots to the question string in the URL at different places.

EDIT: Sorry this seems to be duplicate of ["The resource cannot be found." error when there is a "dot" at the end of the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-url) . I couldn't find it myself before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can set this flag in the system.web section of your web.config and it will be allowed:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I've tested it and it works. [Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) has an explanation of it.

Comment: what about IIS 6 and ASP.NET 4.0? I still have this error at production (iis6) but not at my machine (iis7)

Comment: Сергій, did you resolve your issue? I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336569/iis-6-not-allowing-periods-in-the-querystring