# asp.net MVC routing problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I had made a website [bulkpedia.com](http://bulkpedia.com)
In this i had use `ASP.NET Routing` mechanism in the way

```
{type}/{query}
```

whenever there is a query that contains a period, it shows me a 404 error

e.g. http://bulkpedia.com/web/fb.com

please help me solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of iis are you using?

Comment: Seems to be the same problem like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534366/dot-character-in-asp-net-mvc-3-route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking this in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True" >

  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
<system.webServer>     
  <modules >     
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />     
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />     
    <remove name="Session"/>     
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""/>     
  </modules>     
</system.webServer>
```

Reference: http://www.heartysoft.com/aspnet-routing-iis7-remember-modules

If this is not working either, I believe it might be your IIS or other machine setting.