# How to create a MVC3 Route having dot '.' in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

how to specify Route with static url having dot in it.

```
routes.MapRoute( "RouteForContentFolder", // Route name 
"Content/PDF/ABC.pdf", // URL with parameters 
new { controller = "User", action = "GetPdf"}// Parameter defaults 
);
```

If i specify this route, it directly opens the PDF file without going through the controller and action.

I guess dot in ABC.pdf is the problem.

Can anybody tell me how to specidy dot '.' in static url.

I want this route to function only when the incoming url is

http://www.domainname.com/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worse case you take ABC.Pdf as a parameter to a PDF route and verify it in your controller method..

Comment: Are you saying that you have a static file "/content/pdf/abc.pdf"? If so, physical files will get served up FIRST before .NET attempts to match your requests to known routes. Rename or move your PDF file and the route will work.

Comment: What is the objective of this URL, do you want to open the file after going through the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Route to your controller as you would normally do, then make your controller return the pdf.

Not very extensible to have a fixed route to a resource, imagine if you have two or 10 resources, how much routes to maintain.

Comment: hi,
sorry but my concern is iam not able to route to my controller and action when the url is having . keyword in it like eg: http:domainname.com/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf

Comment: Ok, then you could receive the pdf filename as a parameter.
"Content/PDF/{filename}"

Comment: with that url, the debugger doesnt enter the controller and action method. it directly opens up the .pdf file.

Comment: You never answered my question, is "/content/pdf/abc.pdf" a physical file on the file system?

Comment: @shakti you can refer to this stackoverflow question: [Dot character in ASP.NET MVC 3 route parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534366/dot-character-in-asp-net-mvc-3-route-parameters)

Comment: You can't create a Route that is the same path as a static file!!!!! The physical files will be served up first before any virtual files (routes)

Comment: but i have specified 
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;