# ActionLink route values containing specific characters

Tags: c#, razor, actionlink, routevalues

I am using this action-link to send a route value `id` to controller but my id value like this `config.xml`
and here is my action-link

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Destroy", "DeleteFile", "Files", new { id = "config.xml"})
```

The question is when I want to click this link browser understand this as a `url` that ends with `config.xml`

like this

```
http://localhost:12380/Files/DeleteFile/config.xml
```

and doesn't go to the controller it returns `404 - not found`.
How to prevent this from happening and make this `config.xml` as a parameter not as a file?

here is my route also

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "delete files",
              url: "Files/DeleteFile/{id}",
              defaults: new
              {
                  controller = "Files",
                  action = "DeleteFile",
                  id= UrlParameter.Optional
              }
            );
```

also i tried instead `id ,filename` but nothing changed

and here is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DeleteFile(string id)
        {
          return view("DeleteFile");
         }
```

Comment: here is my action-result
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DeleteFile(string id)
        {
          return view("DeleteFile");
            
        }

Comment: And how does your route look like? Maybe there is a "int"-contraint on it?

Comment: here is my route

 routes.MapRoute(
  name: "delete files",
  url: "Files/DeleteFile/{id}",
  defaults: new
  {
      controller = "Files",
      action = "DeleteFile",
      id= UrlParameter.Optional
  }
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i find the answer we can simply add `/` at the end of the `config.xml`

[here is some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534366/dot-character-in-asp-net-mvc-3-route-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [this overload of Html.ActionLink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Destroy", 
                "DeleteFile", 
                "Files", 
                new RouteValueDictionary { {"file", Url.Encode("config.xml")} }, 
                null)
```

and Action:

```
public ActionResult DeleteFile(string file)
{
  // delete logic here
  return View();
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

[Here is a working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z2Rcmk)

Comment: @Younisbarznji don't use ``id`` as parameter use some other name like i used ``file``, id is changed by routing so it is considered file path

Comment: the point is when i remove .xml from the parameter it is working fine but with .xml understands like a page

Comment: i also tried this i changed to strFileName but still the same

Comment: @Younisbarznji: What link is generated? It should be like `http://localhost:12380/Files/DeleteFile?file=config.xml` and that should work...

Comment: the link is 
http://localhost:12380/Files/DeleteFile/config.xml

it is working like this ?file="config.xml"  but i want to make it without using url like this ?file="config.xml"

Comment: also your demo i tried the link becomes like this 
//localhost:12380/Files/DeleteFile/config.xml

Comment: sure i putted in the question you can see it

Comment: @Younisbarznji remove ``DeleteFiles`` action route and then try

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad i removed but it got error to index file route

Comment: Do you have default route in it?

Comment: Before making post I tested it on my machine also in fiddle, I think you are doing some other mistake

Comment: what you think about ? when i remove .xml it is fine but with .xml gets error

Comment: It's related with routing I guess

Comment: you see my route above is there any mistake , and why it works when remove .xml ?

Comment: Did you used file instead of id in view and action?

Comment: Dear Ehsan i find a solution for this we can just put /  after config.xml  then it wokrs.. thank you for helping me 

also here is a link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534366/dot-character-in-asp-net-mvc-3-route-parameters