# How to send email address as parameter in wcf method

Tags: wcf

This is my operation contract. I want to test this method in a browser. But when I type any email in the browser like `http://localhost:1234/json/user/abc/abc@abc.com`, it does not work

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
 UriTemplate = "json/user/{name}/{email}")]
string addUser(string name, string email);
```

How do I send the email address as a single string?? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try to URL encode your e-mail address:

```
http://localhost:1234/json/user/abc/abc%40abc.com
```

Does that result in the call you expect?

Comment: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for or one of its dependencies, may have been removed or is temporarily unavailable. Check the following URL is spelled correctly.

Comment: what about the (.). do I have to do anything for that?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-to-match-dot-character-at-the-end-in-a-route