# How to send an Email Address in URL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I tried all this answers

[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093800/how-to-send-email-address-as-parameter-in-wcf-method)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-to-match-dot-character-at-the-end-in-a-route)

But all this didn't worked for me , actually I am sending email address as a parameter to a WCF REST service method in URL.

Thanks

Comment: Of what you tried, did you get any progress at all? Any error messages or incorrect sends?

Answer (score -1):

Having the below implemenation i could get the email address passed in URL

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate ="{email}")]
public string GetString(string email)
{
     return "the email address is :" + email;
}
```

the URL i used to get data from resource is:

```
http://localhost/SampleService/test@test.com
```

Comment: the URL specification (RFC1738) forbids the use of the @ symbol in URLs because it's reserved for use within any type of URL.