# IIS 6 not allowing periods in the querystring

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have deployed an asp.net site with a wcf rest service to a virtual directory. It accepts lat/lon in the querystring. IIS is apparently not allowing querystrings that contain a '.'. I have found numerious posts on the topic, but cannot seem to resolve the issue.

I have tried enabling parent paths on both the parent website and the virtual directory:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332117

I have already tried the httpRuntime setting for relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

currently I have both parent paths enabled and my httpRuntime settings are:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Comment: that's strange - I thought . was a perfectly valid character for URL's and Query Strings and didn't need to be encoded. What are you actually seeing when the rest service processes the URL?

Comment: Can you provide a sample url?  http://yoursite.com/service.svc?lat=10.10&log=20.20

Comment: works:
http://localhost/GeoLookupService/AddressLookup/username=testtest&lat=38&lng=-77
rejected:
http://localhost/GeoLookupService/AddressLookup/username=testtest&lat=38.897379&lng=-77.033601

Comment: dash, the rest service never gets the request, iis basically says it does not exist

Comment: From your examples, what you have here isn't actually a query string. Since it isn't separated from the path with a ?, it will be treated with the same rules as a path. Does a URL with a period only in lng work? Also, when it says it does not exist, what is the status code that is returned? Is it a 404 error?

Comment: @JamieSee Yes... that is exactly what I was doing wrong. I updated the UriTemplate of the service to include the ?
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?username={username}&lat={lat}&lng={lng}")]

Post an answer so I can give you props. Thanks

Comment: @Roger I provided an answer for you that tells you how you could override the Uri processing as well as putting this in. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the Urls you were using have a / rather than a ? which causes the elements to be treated as a path rather than a query string.

If that was intended and you are using .NET 4.0, you can try using the [`<schemeSettings>` Element (Uri Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656539.aspx) under configuration:

```
<uri>  
    <schemeSettings> 
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" /> 
    </schemeSettings> 
</uri>
```

See [GenericUriParserOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.genericuriparseroptions.aspx) for the valid values.

If that was not intended update your template to use the ? mark and you should be ok:

`[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?username={username}&lat={lat}&lng={lng}")]`

Answer (score -1):

Probablly not what you were looking for but I would use UrlEncode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: Nope, not what I am looking for. I don't want to force consumers of the service to use urlencoding.

Comment: @Roger, I understand.  Could you substitute the "." for something else that does work and have your service convert it manually.  Bit of a hack again but if you get stuck it is an option.

Comment: No, it's not an option. The service is currently consumed by multiple other services. Those companies would be forced to change their code.

Comment: So it has never worked with "." or did you do something to break it?

Comment: This is a new service in our environment meant to replace a 3rd party that has become unreliable. When I get it setup, it is just config change to these other services to point them to the new url. I do not have the option to break the 'contract' that the existing 3rd party service uses. All this is beside the point. My problem is IIS 6 not allowing the '.' in the querysting. I need a solution to that.