# Dot at the end of URL causes unhandled error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to customise the error pages in the MVC4 application using two approaches:

1.I've covered the case for `Application_Error`:

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("code", errorCode); //this code is from generated exception
routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");            

IController errorController = new ErrorController();
errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

2.Added the "Catch All" route to my route table:

```
RouteHelper.MapRoute(
   "CatchAll",
   "{*catchAll}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = "404" }
);
```

However, I am still encountering a yellow screen of death when I type URL like this (pay attention to the character at the end):

```
localhost/Home/Index.
```

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

I thought that any YSOD should trigger `Application_Error`, but that
doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: As error explain your site failed to report failure. To debug start with breaking on exceptions in your code (Debug->Exception->CLR=throw), if it is not enough - turn off Tool->Options->Debug->"My Code Only" to catch all exceptions.

Comment: Might be of use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541426/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-to-match-dot-character-at-the-end-in-a-route

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it says "Failed to map the path" at `System.Web`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net

Comment: @GirishSakhare link should provide you the solution to immediate problem, but you also look into why your error page failed with exception...

Comment: @GirishSakhare @JasonEvans thank you, that helps to get rid of the exception. But why it is not handled in `Applicaiton_Error` initially?