# Redirect with bypassing having period (dot) and slash in URL

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I have one url which having ./ [period & slash] at the end of parameter. I want to redirect that url with different location but its not even detecting in rules. I am using IIS. I want to configure this on web.config

```
http://somesitename.com/mypage/teachers-manual./sku/8772
```

needs to redirect on

```
http://somesitename.com/mypage/teachers-manual/sku/8772
```

Though I have tried solution given on [Here](http://www.devcurry.com/2015/07/allowing-dots-in-aspnet-mvc-paths.html) but its not even working. But if I use same thing instead of **Redirect** with **Rewrite** then Rule start working. Not sure why its not working for "**Redirect**".

```
<rule name="Trailing Dots and spaces" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^mypage\/(.*)([\.\s]+)\/(.*)" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Actually when I tried to write rule then url which having ./ is also not working.[ http://somesitename.com/mypage/teachers-manual./sku/8772 ]

```
 <rule name="Trailing Dots and spaces1.1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://somesitename.com/newpage.html" />
 </rule>
```

Not sure where its wrong.

Comment: For a difference between Rewrite ans Redirect, see https://forums.iis.net/t/1174487.aspx?How+does+URL+Rewrite+differ+from+HTTP+Redirect+

Comment: Thanks for information but solution is pending.

Comment: Did you check the request filtering for `<denyUrlSequences>` ? https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering

Comment: simon its useful information but there is nothing in denyUrlSequences. Any other alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got more information on [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-ur) & [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/) Said for it.
so I have modified file as follows and now its perfectly working for me.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
        <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
     <rule name="Trailing Dots and spaces1.1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)/(.*)\.\/(.*)" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
 .... etc
```