# Why my JWT token is not passed to controller's method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

My Controller looks like this:

```
    [Route("Test/{token}")]
    public ActionResult Test(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            return this.View(this.jwtService.DecryptJwtToken(token));
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException)
        {
            return this.View("Error");
        }
    }
```

when i type `http://localhost:52006/Test/ddd` im hitting my method. But when i use something like this:

```
http://localhost:52006/Test/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMTUiLCJleHAiOjE1NTY3OTc1MDh9.iza_zuDL8aB7osanbs76rtVzTiBpemNwfNin5zljYwA
```

I get `404 Not found`. I bet its because `JWT` token have dots in his body. My question is, how to pass `JWT` token to my `ASP MVC` method by routing?

Comment: you should add the token to the header as opposed to the route

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know what r you talking about. Could you explain for me, what header is?

Comment: It's a big subject. Here's a link to an example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1203978/JWT-Security-Part-Secure-MVC-application

Comment: Ok, i get it, but there is option to pass it as parameter in my routing?

Comment: If routing does not allow for dot (`.`) then here is quick fix for you that you can make one pattern to accept your jwt token and then send it to server. So the pattern like => `http://localhost:52006/Test?token=$$..................$$` where `$$` is pattern for your token and dots between patterns replace with token.. and then server side just read query string value and extract token between `$$` and `$$`, got it?

Comment: @er-sho replacing dots by `&&` works, thanks

Comment: @michasaucer, glad to hear that it works :)

Comment: @GregH `JWT` spec the string is `Base64Url encoded` and a dot `.` is "fine" for urls...

Comment: I haven't tried the [suggestion of simply adding a `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13397417/304683) if you _can't_ put the `JWT` token in  header as previously suggested..

Comment: @EdSF its not in mvc, because after `dot` server looking for file etc in directory. `$$` works great. Its not too elegant, but works ok when you are good with preprocessing your token