# Allow dot (.) at the end of a URL

Tags: c#, .net, url, routes

I'm creating a C# .net WebAPI using the following route mapping

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithId",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    null,
    new { id = @"\d.+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "UI",
    "{*url}",
    new { Controller = "UI", Action = "Index" }
    );
```

I have several actions of the format `/action/{name}` where the `name` could end with a dot (`.`).
If the dot is anywhere, but at the end of the name, the URL gets resolved properly, but if the dot is at the end, the application says `The resource cannot be found`.

URLs that get resolved

- `https://foobar.com/foo/`
- `https://foobar.com/foo.bar/`
- `https://foobar.com/.foobar/`
- `https://foobar.com/......a/`
- `https://foobar.com/./` (gets converted to `https://foobar.com/`)

URLs that don't get resolved

- `https://foobar.com/foo./`
- `https://foobar.com/foo.bar./`
- `https://foobar.com/.foo.bar./`
- `https://foobar.com/foo.bar`

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-ur)?

Comment: I assume you are running in IIS here? If so, see the link posted by Hamed.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi Thanks, that worked, flagged the question as a duplicate.